Erro while connecting to a rds
I made a small Python 3.9 application to access an RDS MySql db using serverless and pymysql.
RDS is configured to use password authentication only.
I can access the db via MySQL Workbench normally, creating tables, inserts, queries, etc.
I can't access the db via the application, whether running locally (serverless offline) or on AWS, already deployed.
In both situations, I receive the access denied error.
What would be missing?
Below are more details about the application/environment:
```
ERROR

GET /dev (λ: hello)
ERROR:root:Erro abrindo a conex o(1045, "Access denied for user 'myuser'@'152.241.43.211' (using password: YES)")



AWS RDS describe-db-instances

{
    "DBInstances": [
        {
            "DBInstanceIdentifier": "mydb",
            "DBInstanceClass": "db.t3.micro",
            "Engine": "mysql",
            "DBInstanceStatus": "available",
            "MasterUsername": "myuser",
            "Endpoint": {
                "Address": "mydb.xxxxxxxxxx.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com",
                "Port": 3306,
                "HostedZoneId": "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
            },
            "AllocatedStorage": 20,
            "InstanceCreateTime": "2024-04-18T14:43:23.112000+00:00",
            "PreferredBackupWindow": "08:40-09:10",
            "BackupRetentionPeriod": 1,
            "DBSecurityGroups": [],
            "VpcSecurityGroups": [
                {
                    "VpcSecurityGroupId": "sg-99999999",
                    "Status": "active"
                }
            ],
            "DBParameterGroups": [
                {
                    "DBParameterGroupName": "mydbparam",
                    "ParameterApplyStatus": "in-sync"
                }
            ],
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-2a",
            "DBSubnetGroup": {
                "DBSubnetGroupName": "default-vpc-xxxxxxxx",
                "DBSubnetGroupDescription": "Created from the RDS Management Console",
                "VpcId": "vpc-xxxxxxxx",
                "SubnetGr`enter code here`oupStatus": "Complete",
                "Subnets": [
                    {
                        "SubnetIdentifier": "subnet-xxxxxxx",
                        "SubnetAvailabilityZone": {
                            "Name": "us-east-2b"
                        },
                        "SubnetOutpost": {},
                        "SubnetStatus": "Active"
                    },
                    {
                        "SubnetIdentifier": "subnet-xxxxxxxxx",
                        "SubnetAvailabilityZone": {
                            "Name": "us-east-2a"
                        },
                        "SubnetOutpost": {},
                        "SubnetStatus": "Active"
                    },
                    {
                        "SubnetIdentifier": "subnet-xxxxxxxxx",
                        "SubnetAvailabilityZone": {
                            "Name": "us-east-2c"
                        },
                        "SubnetOutpost": {},
                        "SubnetStatus": "Active"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "PreferredMaintenanceWindow": "sun:05:30-sun:06:00",
            "PendingModifiedValues": {},
            "LatestRestorableTime": "2024-04-19T18:10:00+00:00",
            "MultiAZ": false,
            "EngineVersion": "8.0.36",
            "AutoMinorVersionUpgrade": true,
            "ReadReplicaDBInstanceIdentifiers": [],
            "LicenseModel": "general-public-license",
            "OptionGroupMemberships": [
                {
                    "OptionGroupName": "default:mysql-8-0",
                    "Status": "in-sync"
                }
            ],
            "PubliclyAccessible": true,
            "StorageType": "gp2",
            "DbInstancePort": 0,
            "StorageEncrypted": true,
            "KmsKeyId": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-2:999999999999:key/xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx",
            "DbiResourceId": "db-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "CACertificateIdentifier": "rds-ca-rsa2048-g1",
            "DomainMemberships": [],
            "CopyTagsToSnapshot": true,
            "MonitoringInterval": 0,
            "DBInstanceArn": "arn:aws:rds:us-east-2:99999999999:db:MYdb",
            "IAMDatabaseAuthenticationEnabled": false,
            "PerformanceInsightsEnabled": false,
            "DeletionProtection": false,
            "AssociatedRoles": [],
            "MaxAllocatedStorage": 1000,
            "TagList": [],
            "CustomerOwnedIpEnabled": false
        }
    ]
}



SERVERLESS.YML

service: App0001

frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.9
  region: us-east-2
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: /
          method: get
plugins:
  - serverless-wsgi
  - serverless-python-requirements
  - serverless-offline



HANDLER.PY

import json
import pymysql
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

db_username = 'myuser'
db_password = 'mypassword'
db_name = 'dev'
db_endpoint = 'mydb.xxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com'
db_port = 3306


def hello(event, context):
    resposta = {
        'mensagem': [],
    }

    conn = dbConnection()

    if conn is None:
        resposta['mensagem'].append({'level_Error': 'e', 'dsc_error': 'Erro abrindo a conexão'})
        status = 500
    else:
        .
        .

    if conn is not None:
        conn.close()

    response = {
        "statusCode": status,
        "body": json.dumps(resposta)
    }

    return response


def dbConnection():
    conn = None

    try:
        conn = pymysql.connect(host=db_endpoint, user=db_username,
                               passwd=db_password, db=db_name, connect_timeout=5,
                               cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    except pymysql.MySQLError as e:
        logger.error('Erro abrindo a conexão' + str(e))

    return conn
```


LAMBDA DESCRIBE

{
    "Functions": [
        {
            "FunctionName": "App0001-dev-hello",
            "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:9999999999:function:App0001-dev-hello",
            "Runtime": "python3.9",
            "Role": "arn:aws:iam::999999999999:role/App0001-dev-us-east-2-lambdaRole",
            "Handler": "handler.hello",
            "CodeSize": 10309404,
            "Description": "",
            "Timeout": 6,
            "MemorySize": 1024,
            "LastModified": "2024-04-17T22:28:10.000+0000",
            "CodeSha256": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=",
            "Version": "$LATEST",
            "VpcConfig": {
                "SubnetIds": [
                    "subnet-d37494b8",
                    "subnet-59e3bd23",
                    "subnet-b39e1fff"
                ],
                "SecurityGroupIds": [
                    "sg-9187d5f4"
                ],
                "VpcId": "vpc-f01de59b"
            },
            "TracingConfig": {
                "Mode": "PassThrough"
            },
            "RevisionId": "xxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx",
            "PackageType": "Zip"
        }
    ]
}


VPC DESCRIBE

{
    "Vpcs": [
        {
            "CidrBlock": "172.31.0.0/16",
            "DhcpOptionsId": "dopt-a9af72c2",
            "State": "available",
            "VpcId": "vpc-f01de59b",
            "OwnerId": "9999999999999",
            "InstanceTenancy": "default",
            "CidrBlockAssociationSet": [
                {
                    "AssociationId": "vpc-cidr-assoc-217c864a",
                    "CidrBlock": "172.31.0.0/16",
                    "CidrBlockState": {
                        "State": "associated"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "IsDefault": true
        }
    ]
}


SUBNETS DESCRIBE

{
    "Subnets": [
        {
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-2c",
            "AvailabilityZoneId": "use2-az3",
            "AvailableIpAddressCount": 4090,
            "CidrBlock": "172.31.32.0/20",
            "DefaultForAz": true,
            "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": true,
            "MapCustomerOwnedIpOnLaunch": false,
            "State": "available",
            "SubnetId": "subnet-b39e1fff",
            "VpcId": "vpc-f01de59b",
            "OwnerId": "9999999999",
            "AssignIpv6AddressOnCreation": false,
            "Ipv6CidrBlockAssociationSet": [],
            "SubnetArn": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:9999999999:subnet/subnet-b39e1fff"
        },
        {
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-2a",
            "AvailabilityZoneId": "use2-az1",
            "AvailableIpAddressCount": 4089,
            "CidrBlock": "172.31.0.0/20",
            "DefaultForAz": true,
            "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": true,
            "MapCustomerOwnedIpOnLaunch": false,
            "State": "available",
            "SubnetId": "subnet-d37494b8",
            "VpcId": "vpc-f01de59b",
            "OwnerId": "99999999999",
            "AssignIpv6AddressOnCreation": false,
            "Ipv6CidrBlockAssociationSet": [],
            "SubnetArn": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:9999999999999:subnet/subnet-d37494b8"
        },
        {
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-2b",
            "AvailabilityZoneId": "use2-az2",
            "AvailableIpAddressCount": 4090,
            "CidrBlock": "172.31.16.0/20",
            "DefaultForAz": true,
            "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": true,
            "MapCustomerOwnedIpOnLaunch": false,
            "State": "available",
            "SubnetId": "subnet-59e3bd23",
            "VpcId": "vpc-f01de59b",
            "OwnerId": "99999999999",
            "AssignIpv6AddressOnCreation": false,
            "Ipv6CidrBlockAssociationSet": [],
            "SubnetArn": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:9999999999:subnet/subnet-59e3bd23"
        }
    ]
}


Unable to see the subnet settings, but check to see if the subnet is publicly accessible. Use something like PgAdmin to test the connection first. My guess is that either the subnet is not publicly accessible, or that you need an SSH tunnel into your database

@inspectorG4dget, your answer is to set RDS in public subnet? Database/RDS should(MUST) be in private subnet unless you don't care anonymous access.

How is the app connecting to the database -- can you show us the code? Make sure it is using SSL=True.

The code is above. As for the public attribute, I did not find this information in the VPC or subnets.

Are you testing this code locally, or actually running it on AWS Lambda? If Lambda, is it in the same VPC as the RDS instance?

Here's more information to try to find the problem:
Some forum colleagues mention details of the code. It is described in the initial post. It is a simple application, with the aim of connecting to the db.
Also in the initial post, db details.
Added descriptions about lambda, vpc and subnets in initial post

Any more tips?
I had already done tests on that same account and it worked ok. Some time later I removed rds because I wasn't using it.
Soon after I created the rds again. From then on I couldn't make it work anymore.
As for the vpc and subnets, I never created any, nor did I make any association.

I removed the application, local and from AWS. I created a new one, deployed it and it worked. I do not know what to say...
